# Trouble reading file into array of structs in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have an input text file that contains:

```
1234,123456781,"Smith","Bob A.",ABC, 123,="A01"
1234,123456782,"Jones","Tom Jr",ABC, 123,="A03"  
1234,123456783,"Michaels","Mike",ABC, 123,="A03"
```

this is what the output is supposed to look like.

```
Last Name, First Name            Term      ID      Course   Section 
-------------------------------- ----  ---------   ------   ------- 
Jones, Tom Jr.                   1234  123456782   ABC123     A03 
Michaels, Mike                   1234  123456783   ABC123     A03 
Smile, Bob A.                    1234  123456781   ABC123     A01
```

I'm having a lot of trouble reading the information from the text file into an array of structs. It must be implemented in this fashion and then printed/displayed to the user.

Here is my code so far... been working on this for days!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//The values included in the source text file.
typedef struct items{
    char fname[16];
    int cat;
    char lname[16];
    char sub[4];
    int term;
    int  sID;
    char sec[4];
}STRING;

void formatOut(){
    //Output format
    printf("\n\n\nLast Name, First Name            Term      ID      Course   Section");
    printf("\n-------------------------------- ----  ---------   ------   ------- ");
}



int main(){

int count;
count=0;
int i=0;

FILE* fp;
struct items item[200];

//Finds The File
char file_name[25];
printf("Enter the name of file that includes your data. Be sure to write your file extension.\n(For example, source.txt is a valid entry, source is invalid)\n");

gets(file_name);

fp = fopen(file_name,"r");

//Actions to take incase the file does not exist.
if(fp == NULL){
    perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
//Making things neater.
printf("__________________________________\n\n");
printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", file_name);


//Retrieve data from txt file

do{ fscanf(fp,"%d %d %s %s %s %d %s", &item[i].term, &item[i].sID, item[i].lname, item[i].fname,item[i].sub, &item[i].cat, &item[i].sec);
    printf("Term:%d\n", item[count].term);
    printf("Student ID:%d\n", item[count].sID);
    printf("LastName:%c\n,", item[count].lname);
    printf("FirstName:%s\n", item[count].fname);
    printf("Subject:%s\n", item[count].sub);
    printf("Category:%d\n", item[count].cat);
    printf("Section:%s\n", item[count].sec);
    i++;
}while(fscanf(fp,"%d %d %s %s %s %d %s", &item[i].term, &item[i].sID, item[i].lname, item[i].fname, item[i].sub, &item[i].cat, item[i].sec>1));

/*
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    fscanf(fp,"%d", &item[count].term);
    fscanf(fp,"%d", &item[count].sID);
    fscanf(fp,"%s", &item[count].lname);
    fscanf(fp,"%s", &item[count].fname);
    fscanf(fp,"%s", &item[count].sub);
    fscanf(fp,"%d", &item[count].cat);
    fscanf(fp,"%s", &item[count].sec);

    printf("Term:%d\n", item[count].term);
    printf("Student ID:%d\n", item[count].sID);
    printf("LastName:%s\n,", item[count].lname);
    printf("FirstName:%s\n", item[count].fname);
    printf("Subject:%s\n", item[count].sub);
    printf("Category:%d\n", item[count].cat);
    printf("Secton:%s\n", item[count].sec);
    count++;
}
 */

fclose(fp);
formatOut();

}
```

This is what my output currently looks like:

```
Term:1301
Student ID:0
LastName:\364
FirstName:
Subject:
Category:0
Section:



Last Name, First Name            Term      ID      Course   Section
-------------------------------- ----  ---------   ------   -------
```

Clearly the array of structs is not receiving the correct values. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What specific problem are you having?

Comment: I just added my output. The issue I am having is that I do not think my array of structures is receiving the right data or value from the text file I am trying to read from. Take a look at my text file, the correct output, and then my incorrect output, and then refer to my code.

Comment: @user3404487 I edited the details of your private data out of the question, but left the code, because someone may find it useful. Your data is still in the edit log, however, so you may need to talk to a mod to purge it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best practice is to set some breakpoints and `DEBUG` it step by step to see whether there is any problem. This is also the best way to improve your coding and debugging skill.

Please:

1. change the while statement to:

   ```
   while(fscanf(fp,"%d,%d,\"%[^\"]\",\"%[^\"]\",%[^,],%d,=\"%[^\"]\"", &item[i].term, &item[i].sID, item[i].lname, item[i].fname,item[i].sub, &item[i].cat, &item[i].sec)>1)
   {
       printf("Term:%d\n", item[i].term);
       printf("Student ID:%d\n", item[i].sID);
       printf("LastName:%s\n,", item[i].lname);
       printf("FirstName:%s\n", item[i].fname);
       printf("Subject:%s\n", item[i].sub);
       printf("Category:%d\n", item[i].cat);
       printf("Section:%s\n", item[i].sec);
       i++;
   }
   ```

   the most important change is the `format` of `fscanf`. `%[\"]` means reading the following string until the next `"`.

   ```
   1234,123456789, "  Smith  " , "  Bob A. " , ABC  , 123,= "  A01     "
    |  |    |    | |    |    | | |    |    | |  |   |  | || |   |      |
   %d  ,   %d    , \" %[^\"] \", \" %[^\"] \",%[^,] , %d ,= \" %[^\"]  \"
   ```
2. initialize the `item`: `struct items item[200]={0};`.

Actually you could try to clean all the warnings, the compiler would give very useful information. Don't ignore them is a very good habit.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 5 and its giving me warnings, not necessarily errors. I don't know exactly what the issue is, but this is what the warning reports.

http://i61.tinypic.com/dp8e3s.png

Comment: @user3404487 use %s while printing lname, as it is an char array and not one charcter.

Comment: @user3404487, please take a look the updated answer, it would give you the right values.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. The format of fscanf to only read one string at a time was the main issue for me. This example sheds so much light. Now I can continue with the rest of the program. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You should change the lname as an array, same like your fname, these structures have to be filled accordingly to the char array converted to its specific data types.

```
typedef struct items{
    char fname[16];
    int cat;
    char lname[16];
    char sub[4];
    int term;
    int  sID;
    char sec[4];
}STRING;
```

you need to convert `sID, term, cat` using `atoi()`, since you have an integer in your code and what you will read is an char * from file.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to add back the array when I was messing around with it. If I have to convert sID (referring to studentID), would i have to convert term and category too?

Comment: @user3404487 yes you need to convert them also, I was just editing the answer again.